# How can I print a specific set of data in Python 3.9, from a column of a CSV file based on two sets of descriptors from two other columns?

Tags: python, excel, csv, spreadsheet, python-3.9

I have an assignment to print specific data within a CSV file.  The data to be printed are the registration numbers of vehicles caught by the camera at a location whose descriptor is stored in the variable search_Descriptor, during an hour specified in the variable search_HH.

The CSV file is called: Carscaught.csv

All the registration numbers of the vehicles are under the column titled: Plates.
The descriptors are locations where the vehicles were caught, under the column titled: Descriptor.
And the hours of when each vehicles were caught are under the column titled: HH.

This is the file, it's quite big so I have shared it from google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zhIxg5s_nVGzk_5JUXkujbetSIuUcNRU/view?usp=sharing

This is an image of a few lines of the CSV file from the top, the actual data on the file fills 3170 rows and goes all the way from 0-23 hours on the "HH" column:

[Carscaught.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xYIF.png)

In my code I have defined two variables as I want to print only the registration plates of vehicles that were caught at the Location of "Kilburn Bldg" specifically at "17" hours:

```
search_Descriptor = "Kilburn Bldg"

search_HH = "17"
```

This is the code I have used, but have no clue how to go further by using the variables defined to print the specific data I need.  And I HAVE to use those specific variables as they are shown, by the way.

```
search_Descriptor = "Kilburn Bldg"
search_HH = "17"

fo = open ('Carscaught.csv', 'r')
counter = 0;

line = fo.readline()
while line:
    print(line, end = "")
    line = fo.readline();
    counter = counter + 1;

fo.close()
```

All that code does is read the entire entire file and closes it.  I have no idea on how to get the desired output which should be these three specific registration numbers:

```
JOHNZS
KEENAS
KR8IVE
```

Hopefully you can help me with this.  Thank you.

Comment: I've posted an image with a few lines of the file.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "python csv"? That should bring up the documentation with a lot of examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
(of course you could also use pandas if necessary)

Comment: If you want, you can use pandas to easily define the conditions you want.

Comment: By the way, since you are new here, if you find a solution/answer working, you should mark it as "resolved" by accepting it.   Check this to know more https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

You possible want to look at [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
with open('Carscaught.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        plate = row['Plates']
        hour = row['HH']
        minute = row['MM']
        descriptor = row['Descriptor']
        if descriptor in search_Descriptor:
            print("Found a row, now to check time")
```

Then you can use simple logic to search for the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

search_Descriptor = "Kilburn Bldg"
search_HH = 17 # based on the csv that you have posted above, HH is int and not str so I removed the quotation marks

df = pd.read_csv("Carscaught.csv")
df2 = df[df["Descriptor"].eq(search_Descriptor) & df["HH"].eq(search_HH)]
df3 = df2["Plates"]

print(df3)
```

Output (the numbers 1636, 1648, and 1660 are their row numbers):

```
1636    JOHNZS
1648    KEENAS
1660    KR8IVE
```

If you don't have pandas yet, there are different tutorials on how to download/use it depending on where are you writing your code.